# Out-of-Band Bluetooth pairing with the btmgmt tool on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, pairing, out-of-band

Is it possible to have Bluetooth BR/EDR Out-of-Band (OOB) pairing using the **btmgmt** tool on Linux?
I used the **local-oob** and **remote-oob** commands between 2 Linux machines (machines A and B). In machine A, I generate the Hash H_a and Random R_a from **btmgmt local-oob** command and in machine B I use the same command to generate the Hash H_b and Random R_b.

I configured machine A with

```
# btmgmt remote-oob -R R_b -C H_b machine_B_BT_address
```

and I configured machine B with

```
# btmgmt remote-oob -R R_a -C H_a machine_A_BT_address
```

I then started the pairing in machine A and in machine B **btmon** shows that machine A pairing request does not have OOB data flag on.
Maybe I am using OOB in a wrong way in this scenario. Can someone tell me how to establish an OOB pairing using this simple scenario?

Thanks!